# MVC posting IPagedList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, pagedlist

I have the following PagedListModel:

```
public class PagedClientViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public PagedList.IPagedList<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; set; }               
}

public class ClientViewModel
{        
    public string ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public bool UseThisClient{ get; set; }
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "Form" }))
{
    @foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
    {
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientNumber)
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.UseThisClient)
    }    

 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Clients)            
}
```

Controller Action:

```
 public ActionResult Index(PagedClientViewModel model)
 {
  //...process all clients in the list
 }
```

I want to post the model back to the controller so that I can process which checkboxes have been ticked, but I get the following error: I kind of understand that the error is because I'm posting back an interface but I cant find a way around that. How can I get this work?

> Cannot create an instance of an interface.     at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)     at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindSimpleModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
>   PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_1e(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: There are ways around this problem which I have used in my project in past. But let me ask you this first - Do you have to post and interface type instead of a concrete class type?

Comment: I think I do have to post the interface type as when I populate the list of clients I need to call `model.Clients = clients.ToPagedList(pageIndex, 25);` which returns the interface type. I have tried to convert the `IPagedList<ClientViewModel>` to a `PagedList<ClientViewModel>` but havent succeeded.

Comment: This worked for me in the end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356152/pagedlistpager-pass-additional-model-data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Work around for this problem is to pass the paging meta data as separate property and reconstruct the IPagedList in the view. Like below

```
public class PagedClientViewModel
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public List<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; set; }
    public IPagedList PagingMetaData { get; set; } 
}
```

gererating th metadata

```
pagedClientViewModel.PagingMetaData = new StaticPagedList<ClientViewModel>(pagedClientViewModel.Clients, pageIndex, pageSize, TotalClients).GetMetaData();
```

constructing the pager in the view

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    @Html.PagedListPager(new StaticPagedList<ClientViewModel>(Model.Clients, Model.PagingMetaData), page => Url.Action("<actionname>", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.Classic)
</div>
```