# PagedListPager pass additional model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have the following model:

```
  public class PagedClientViewModel
    {
        public int? Page { get; set; }
        public PagedList.PagedList<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; set; }               
        public bool ShowAllClients { get; set; }
    }
```

ShowAllClients is a checkbox that I'll use to further filter the list of clients returned from the server.

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ShowAllClients, new { id = "ShowAllClientsCheckbox" })
```

Here is my pager:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Clients, page => Url.Action("Index", new { Page = page }), PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)
```

Both the pager and checkbox are on the same form.

The problem that I'm having is that when I change page on the pager control, the checkbox is always set to false. This is happening because in the Index action, ShowAllClients is set to false.

How would I preserve the checkbox data when changing pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got this to work with the following:

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Clients, page => Url.Action("Index", new PagedClientViewModel { Page = page, ShowAllClients = Model.ShowAllClients }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution if found so far is:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Clients, page => Url.Action("Index", new { Page = page, param1="",param2="" }), PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)
```

And yes it works.

Comment: Thanks for quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Model is the PagedList.IPagedList. Next to that I use a "SearchModel" which I store in the ViewBag so it can easily be passed along. All I need to update is the page number.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page =>
{
    ViewBag.SearchModel.Page = page;
    return Url.Action("Index", "Search", ViewBag.SearchModel);
})
```