# Cannot create an instance of an interface (PagedList)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I have a view model object that contains a `List` of another model object type. When the user does a query on the page, if the `List` returned contains more than 300 records we want to use paging to keep the loading time down (some search results can return more than 14k records). The paging plugin we're using [can be found here.](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)

Once the results have been displayed on the page, the user has the ability to click a check box next to specific results, type in some information in an input text box, hit submit, and have the selected records edited with the information from the text box.

Since we needed to use an `IPagedList<>` in order to enable paging, however, when you hit submit (and before the page even hits the controller) we get the following error:

```
                 Cannot create an instance of an interface.
```

**View Model**

These are the two list objects that we use for paging. The `zipCodeTerritory` object holds the results of the query. The `pagedTerritoryList` is used to display only the results on the specific page the user is on.

```
    //Paging List objects
    public IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory> pagedTerritoryList { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
    public IPagedList PagingMetaData { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

This is our basic search. The `.ToPagedList` method is used to specify what range of results we want to display and place them in the `pagedTerritoryList` object.

```
                //set Paged List counter variables
                int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
                int pageSize = 300;

                //Determine if Territory present?
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchTerritory))
                {
                    //State Code ONLY search
                    search.zipCodeTerritory = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                               where z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState)
                                               select z).ToList();
                }
                else if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.searchState))
                {
                    //Territory ONLY search
                    search.zipCodeTerritory = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                               where z.IndDistrnId.Equals(search.searchTerritory)
                                               select z).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Territory AND state search
                    search.zipCodeTerritory = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                               where z.IndDistrnId.Equals(search.searchTerritory) &&
                                                     z.StateCode.Equals(search.searchState)
                                               select z).ToList();
                }

                //Convert list to IPagedList for pagining on Index
                search.pagedTerritoryList = search.zipCodeTerritory.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

                //Set Paged List objects
                search.PagingMetaData = new StaticPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory>(search.zipCodeTerritory, pageNumber, pageSize,
                                                                      search.zipCodeTerritory.Count).GetMetaData();

                return View(search);
```

**View**

This is the form that displays the search results. If a user checks the check box, then hits either `clone` or `delete` buttons, the results are supposed to be posted back to the controller's `Update` method and appropriate edits or deletes performed. The information the user wants to overlay in an edit are input into the `newTerritory/Description/etc` fields in the form (above the `table`).

Regarding the `@Html.PagedListPager` I found I had to pass back to the index method the same search criteria from the page, thus the excessive amount of parameters in the `RouteValueDictionary`.

```
@if (Model.zipCodeTerritory.Count > 0)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "ZipCodeTerritory", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchZip)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.searchState)

        <div id="cloneBox">
            <div id="rw1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newTerritory)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newTerritory, new { style = "width: 30px;padding-left:10px;", maxLength = 3 })
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newDescription)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newDescription, new { style = "width: 250px;padding-left:10px;", maxLength = 30 })  
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newEffectiveDate)     
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newEffectiveDate, new { style = "width: 80px;padding-left:10px;" }) 
                <div id="rw2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newChannelCode)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.newChannelCode, Model.ChannelCodes, " ")
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.newStateCode)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.newStateCode, Model.StateCodes, "  ")
                </div>                                 
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="buttonDiv">
            <button type="submit" id="CloneButton" name="button" value="clone">Apply New Data</button>
            <button type="submit" id="deleteButton" name="button" value="delete">Delete Selected Items</button>            
        </div>


        @*Display paging only if necessary*@
        if (Model.pagedTerritoryList.Count >= 300)
        {
           <div id="pagingDiv">
               @Html.PagedListPager(new StaticPagedList<Monet.Models.ZipCodeTerritory>(Model.zipCodeTerritory, Model.PagingMetaData) , 
            Page => Url.Action("Index", new RouteValueDictionary()
               {
                   { "Page", Page},
                   { "searchZip", Model.searchZip },
                   { "searchActiveOnly", Model.searchActiveOnly },
                   { "searchDate", Model.searchDate },
                   { "searchState", Model.searchState },
                   { "searchTerritory", Model.searchTerritory },
                   { "searchChannel" , Model.searchChannelCode }
               }), PagedListRenderOptions.DefaultPlusFirstAndLast)
           </div>            
        }

        <table id="thetable" class="tablesorter" >
            <thead>
                <th>@Html.CheckBox("SelectAll")</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Territory</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Effective</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Last Update Date</th>
                <th>Channel</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.pagedTerritoryList.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr id="@(Model.lastEditedId == Model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Id ? "lastEdit" : "")">
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Update)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].Update)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].StateCode)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].StateCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].IndDistrnId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].IndDistrnId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ZipCode)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zipCodeTerritory[i].ZipCode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].DrmTerrDesc)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].DrmTerrDesc)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EffectiveDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EffectiveDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EndDate.Date != DateTime.MaxValue.Date)
                            {
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EndDate)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].EndDate)                                
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].LastUpdateDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].LastUpdateDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ChannelCode)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.pagedTerritoryList[i].ChannelCode)
                        </td>

                        @if (ViewBag.SecurityLevel >= 4)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new
                                    {
                                        id = Model.zipCodeTerritory[i].Id,
                                        searchZip = Model.searchZip,
                                        searchActiveOnly = Model.searchActiveOnly,
                                        searchDate = Model.searchDate,
                                        searchState = Model.searchState,
                                        searchTerritory = Model.searchTerritory,
                                        searchChannelCode = Model.searchChannelCode
                                    })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.zipCodeTerritory[i].Id)
                            </td>                            
                        }

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Per the comment below, here is the signature for the method the form is posting to. It contains an instance of the `ZipCodeIndex` that gets loaded on the page originally, plus the text from the `button` to determine whether we're doing a `clone` or `delete`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(ZipCodeIndex updateZip, string button)
    {
```

**Second Edit**

Tried the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258212/mvc-posting-ipagedlist) but still receiving the original error message ("cannot create instance of an interface").

Comment: If the error happens before the controller but after the submit, then we would probably need the code before the controller. Possibly the signatures of the controller and view.

Comment: Good point, just posted in an edit above. thanks!

Comment: you are not passing the page int the signature.

Comment: I've found that models with interfaces as properties will need to have a ModelBinder created to determine which implementation to use.

Comment: @DarthVader: Don't need to pass the page int to the `Update` action. The page will reset once the update is complete.

Comment: @ps2goat: Any chance you could point me towards an example of what that is? Relatively new to ASP MVC.

Comment: @NealR I added an answer that points to a similar SO question (minus the interface-specifics).  That question has an accepted answer with a few model binder examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to completely hack my way out of this, however I don't think it's the best solution. Would love it if someone could provide a better answer however I'll post this up here in the meantime.

Since the `IPagedList` object was built to hold a specific range of the `List<>` I just made a display property on my view model and used this on my view. This list, not the `IPagedList` gets posted back to the controller for the updates, so no interface weirdness occurs.

**View Model**

```
    //Paging List objects
    public IPagedList<ZipCodeTerritory> pagedTerritoryList { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipCodeTerritory { get; set; }
    public List<ZipCodeTerritory> displayForPaging { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
    //Convert list to IPagedList for pagining on Index
    search.pagedTerritoryList = search.zipCodeTerritory.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    search.displayForPaging = search.pagedTerritoryList.ToList();
```

**View**

```
    <td>
         @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.displayForPaging[i].Update)
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.displayForPaging[i].Update)
    </td>
    <td>
     .
     .
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that models with interfaces as properties will need to have a ModelBinder created to determine which implementation to use.

[ASP.Net MVC Custom Model Binding explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193453/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binding-explanation)

Basically, your binder will parse your model for you, determining which type of IPagedList<> to implement.

Comment: Was that `public IPagedList PagingMetaData { get; set; }`?

Comment: @SH-In a roundabout way I think so.